# Не могу загрузить конфигурационный scss файл во vuejs используя sass-resources-loader

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

**webpack.base.conf.js**

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      loaders: {
        scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
        sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
    options: {
      resources: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/scss/_variables.scss')
    }
  },
```

Файл начинает грузиться, но затем я получаю эту ошибку:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| $white: #ffffff;
| 
| // The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
```

Иду по этому руководству:

https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html

vue version: 2.93

Comment: Вы указали lang? `<style lang="sass">`

Comment: У тега style в компоненте <style lang="scss">. Но проблема похоже не в <style lang>, а в том что мне нужно где то в конфигах указать lang для _variables.scss ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конечном итоге я создал новый проект используя vue-cli@3 и добавил во **vue.config.js** следующий код:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const oneOfsMap = config.module.rule('scss').oneOfs.store
    oneOfsMap.forEach(item => {
      item
        .use('sass-resources-loader')
        .loader('sass-resources-loader')
        .options({
          resources: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/scss/_variables.scss'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/scss/_mixins.scss'),
          ]
        })
        .end()
    })
  }
}
```